# Sed Grouping with a Tab

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to sed the test.md file:

```
/Dropbox/Notes/test.md:TODO something to eat or todo
/Dropbox/Notes/test.md:todo something blue
/Dropbox/Notes/test.md:Todo mixed
```

to

```
TODO something to eat or todo    file:///Dropbox/Notes/test.md
todo something blue              file:///Dropbox/Notes/test.md
Todo mixed                       file:///Dropbox/Notes/test.md
```

so far I came up with this command

```
cat test.md | sed  "s/\(.*\):\(TODO\) \(.*\)/\2 \3    file\:/\1/gp"
```

However, I get an "Unknown option for s" error. Also I would also like the path description being delimitated by a TAB.

I am using GNU sed.

Comment: `awk` is better in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` with different sets of delimiter and then pipe it to `column` by specifying a particular delimiter for pretty printing.

```
$ sed 's|\([^:]*\):\(.*\)|\2,file:///\1|' file | column -ts','
TODO something to eat or todo  file:////Dropbox/Notes/test.md
todo something blue            file:////Dropbox/Notes/test.md
Todo mixed                     file:////Dropbox/Notes/test.md
```

- We use `|` as our `sed` delimiter
- Using capture groups we capture the two pieces (filename and text) from your input
- In our replacement we add the necessary text along with a delimiter `,`
- This `,` delimiter is for `column` to separate the two context for pretty printing.

Comment: This out put generates spaces as a delimiter. Can I change it to a real TAB?

Comment: @N_2 If you have gnu sed you can use `sed 's|\([^:]*\):\(.*\)|\2\tfile:///\1|' file` if you want tab separation but it won't be pretty as column output. Note that with this you will not be piping it to `column`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want nicely formatted output, it might be easier using `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{printf "%-40sfile://%s\n", $2, $1}' inputfile
```

`-40` specifies the width of the first field as 40 characters and left justifies it.  `s` denotes that it is a character string.

For your input, it'd produce:

```
TODO something to eat or todo           file:///Dropbox/Notes/test.md
todo something blue                     file:///Dropbox/Notes/test.md
Todo mixed                              file:///Dropbox/Notes/test.md
```

Your `sed` expression doesn't work because you have an unescaped `/` in the replacement:

```
sed  "s/\(.*\):\(TODO\) \(.*\)/\2 \3    file:\/\1/gp"
                                              ^
```

(You escaped the `:` instead of the slash.)

Answer (score 2):

The direct problem in your `sed` script is that you have slashes in the replacement text as well as in the `s///` command:

```
sed  "s/\(.*\):\(TODO\) \(.*\)/\2 \3    file\:/\1/gp"
       ^                      ^               ^  ^
       1                      2               3  4
```

Slash 3 is the interloper here.  You can fix it in several different ways:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\):\([Tt][Oo][Dd][Oo]\) \(.*\)/\2 \3    file\:\/\/\1/g'
sed -e 's%\(.*\):\([Tt][Oo][Dd][Oo]\) \(.*\)%\2 \3    file\://\1%g'
```

The first uses backslashes to escape the slashes that are part of the replacement string (the fixed code also introduces two slashes for the `file://` prefix).  The second changes the delimiter from slash to percent `%`.  This is the way I'd do it.  I also enclosed the whole expression in single quotes, which is generally safer — the shell interprets none of the characters inside single quotes. I also made the match for `ToDo` case-insensitive.  Depending on the extra facilities in your `sed`, there may be other ways to do that, but it works when written as shown.

I removed the `p` qualifier to prevent you getting two lines of output for each matching line of input.  If you only want the matching lines, then you need to refine operations to:

```
sed -n -e '/\(.*\):\([Tt][Oo][Dd][Oo]\) \(.*\)/ s%%\2 \3    file\://\1%gp'
```

Now the pattern only matches ToDo lines and the modified version is written.

Comment: They both do, because of the `p` at the end without the `-n` option.  I plead guilty to copying too much code from the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's|\(.*\):\([tT][oO][dD][oO][^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]\(.*\)|\2 \3 file://\1|' YourFile
```

using posix version (-e on GNU sed) where there is no option for genreic capital/small letter pattern
use of `|`as separator to allow the simple `/` after `file:`

could also be (for this sample structucture)

```
sed 's|\([^:]*\):\(.*\)|\2 file://\1|' YourFile
```